# Calling javascript via AS3 externalinterface within a colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, actionscript-3, colorbox

I have a swf that opens up inside a colorbox window. When the video finishes playing, I make an externalinterface call to a javascript function to close the colorbox.

I'm trying to execute the following AS3 code:

`ExternalInterface.call('parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()')`

I can't seem to get this to work. The colorbox won't close.

I also tried this to see if I was just making the wrong function call, but this didn't work either:
`ExternalInterface.call('alert("hello world")')`

However, if I browse to the url of the swf file, so that it doesn't open inside the colorbox, the alert() call works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ExternalInterface.call('parent.$.fn.colorbox.close');
```

And this:

```
ExternalInterface.call('alert','hello world');
```

Alternatively, you could call `eval` and pass JS code as a String (you don't need this here, but it's handy in some cases).

```
ExternalInterface.call('eval','parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()')
```

Comment: @user362871. Maybe your embed code is denying your swf access to JS... Can you paste your embed code?

Comment: I don't have it embedded. I am using colorbox to load the swf directly. Will try embedding it in an html page and calling that with colorbox.

Comment: I got it to work by calling an html file that contained the swf. When I placed a javascript function in the html file that called parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(), and called it from the ExternalInterface command then it worked.

Comment: @user362871. Glad you sorted it out. Must be some kind of security sandbox restriction.

Comment: Don't use eval, its evil it said some bad things about you.